# Headless resolution in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've been trying various things with no avail to change the resolution on a virtual machine while running in headless mode. Is this even possible?

Comment: Hi, what is your ultimate goal ? Without any context, this seems clearly pointless.

Comment: I'm running a surface automated solution for a client and need it to run at a higher resolution, so the plan is to set it at the start then set it back at the end

Comment: Can you give more details and show what you have tried so far ? I mean, for example, how is your VM *headless* ? Is a display device temporarily connected to it ? What PS version and OS are you using ? Have you run any code on it ?(you can edit the question for readability)